# Google Voice on Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-voice

I have never made a call on Google Voice before.

If I try calling "Sweden", after clicking on the phone icon, is it an actual voice call, or do I text them, and they text back?

Also, is Google Voice able to call for free? There seems to be a charge on the side of the calling bar.

Comment: Google Voice phone calls are free to/from the U.S. and Canada, but cost for international calls. The rest of your question is unclear.

Answer (score -1):

Google is starting to phase out Google Voice and integrating it into Hangouts. Here is how to [send text messages from Hangouts](https://support.google.com/voice/answer/6023920?hl=en).

As far as rates go, here is the [rates list](https://www.google.com/voice/b/0/rates).